# Problema com valor de string

Tags: javascript, string

Estou utilizando uma API do Microsofot Graph para obter alguns dados e preciso usar um dos valores que ele me retorna para fazer um UPDATE.

O problema é que o valor retornado possui aspas e barras.

Através do GRAPH EXPLORES (uma interface grafica para testar requisições) um exemplo de valor é:

```
"@odata.etag": "W/\"JzEtVGFza0RldGFpbHMgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBARCc=\""
```

Quando eu utilizo a API via javascript o valor retornado ja se torna:

```
"@odata.etag": "W/"JzEtVGFza0RldGFpbHMgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBARCc=""
```

Esse valor retornado eu preciso utilizar no header de uma requisição:

```
"If-Match": "W/\"JzEtVGFza0RldGFpbHMgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBARCc=\"",
```

Colocando por extenso funciona, mas utilizando a variavel retornada do javascript não funciona, diz que o If-Match é inválido.

Alguma ideia de como contornar esse problema?

Comment: Vc usa uma variável, tipo: `"If-Match": variavel,`, onde o valor de `variavel` deveria ser `"W/\"JzEtVGFza0RldGFpbHMgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBARCc=\""`?

Comment: Exatamente @Sam

Comment: Tente escapando todas as aspas duplas: `variavel = variavel.replace(/"/g, '\\"');`